# Show/ Hide Table Column without hiding table header using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that hide and show in http://jsfiddle.net/kZFqA/ want to hide only the column not header .also when hiding column i want to show that Show Associate inside the header .when i again click Show Associate it will disappear from header and to show the hidden column..

Please any one answer how to d that...

```
$('.associateHide').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var hideClass = associateHideClass; 
    associateHTMLElements = HideSection(hideClass, associateStartElementString);

    $('.btnAssociate').show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your classes (such as `tableColGroupAssociate` and `tableColGroupTransaction`) from the `th` element and add it directly to your `td` elements.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use table body
<tbody>content here</tbody>
$(".associateHide tbody").hide();  //use hide and show
```